# Webkit- css changing with duration

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to turn a grayscale image to colored when the page get loaded.

In my code, I put it grayscale, then with JQuery I tried to turn the grayscale to 0, it's getting colored, but has no effect of duration.

My CSS code:

```
#mainimg{-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#mainimg')
    .css("-webkit-filter" ,"none")
    .css("-moz-filter" , "none")
    .css("filter", "none")
    duration: 10});
```

Where am I wrong?
Or should I use other code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the syntax error in your code, use this:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
     $('#mainimg')
     .css("-webkit-filter" ,"none")
     .css("-moz-filter" , "none")
     .css("filter", "none")
     //duration: 10}); syntax error here
});
```

If you want to animate your grayscale filter use [css transition](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-css3-transitions-20131119/). I created the [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/frontenddeveloping/n65TY/1/) for with `filters` and `css transition`.